# Java ThreadPoolExecutor - Shutdown specific thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am programming my Systems Programming course assignment (which uses Threads).

My active classes implement runnable, and I have another class with an executor that executes that runnable using a : `ThreadPoolExecutor e = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(number);`

I have several threads running at the same time in that thread pool. My question is as follows: I have the option to know when one thread has finished its' job regarding what it needs to do, how can I shut this thread down, and -only- this thread, not the whole executor?

Comment: If you didn't shutdown down this thread which is not doing anything immediately what difference would it make?

Comment: Because I want another thread that is waiting to take its' place?

Comment: And you don't see that happening?  If that is the case I suggest you get another OS.  Windows and Unix will always stop idle threads and start thread which are waiting to run.

Answer (score 1):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` is in charge of managing its threads and there is no way for you to access them, except by some ugly hacks that will probably break the executor. What you should use is configuration options provided by the API, such as `setKeepAliveTime` or the constructor that accepts `keepAliveTime`. Set this to zero and you have the behavior you want, automatically.

Comment: I am sorry, can I get further explanation please? I did not understand the java doc for setKeepAliveTime.
What does it do? is it regarding a certain thread in the pool or the whole pool? and why that if I set it to zero it would get me the behaviour I want automatically?

Comment: Aren't "has nothing to do" and "is waiting" synonymous? Explain what you mean.

Comment: Sometimes a thread is waiting for let us say certain equipment to be released by other threads, and then it executes. setKeepAliveTime does not kill those threads that are currently waiting, right?

Comment: Don't confuse "thread" with "task". If you submit a *task* to the executor, as long as the task doesn't complete, the thread is occupied by that task.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood it correctly what you want is [`newCachedThreadPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29) instead of `newFixedThreadPool`

From Java doc

> Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available. These pools will typically improve the performance of programs that execute many short-lived asynchronous tasks. Calls to execute will reuse previously constructed threads if available. If no existing thread is available, a new thread will be created and added to the pool. **Threads that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed from the cache. Thus, a pool that remains idle for long enough will not consume any resources.** Note that pools with similar properties but different details (for example, timeout parameters) may be created using ThreadPoolExecutor constructors.

Comment: This would've been perfect if it does not automatically expand its' number of threads, because in my assignment I have to personally check that.